# remove "one" action from multi actions in target-action UIbutton

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, target-action

```
[_btt1 addTarget:self action:@selector(clicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[_btt1 addTarget:self action:@selector(clicked2:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

There are 2 actions in _btt1.

```
2013-05-31 10:33:31.300 testTargetAndSelector[6029:c07] actions : (
    "clicked:",
    "clicked2:"
)
```

I remove clicked2 action like this.

```
[_btt1 removeTarget:self action:@selector(clicked2:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

but there is no action in _btt1.

```
2013-05-31 10:33:32.731 testTargetAndSelector[6029:c07] actions : (null)
```

How can I remove single action from multi Actions?

Comment: Don't know why this happened. But why do you need to remove a target? I think you can do something inside the action rather than remove the action.

Comment: I know that. but it is the easiest and simple way I think, although it has problem.